# Differentiability of a function at a point 2

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I would like some help with checking if the following function is differentiable

$$\frac{\sin^4(x+y)}{e^{\cos(x-y)}}$$

at the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: The partial derivatives of first order are continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ so...

Comment: @lxion can you show that using the limit definition?

Comment: Have you checked if it's continuous first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show differentiability, we must show the following exists as $x,y$ approaches from any direction.
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\dfrac{\sin^4(x+y)}{e^{-\cos(x-y)}}-\dfrac{\sin^4(0+0)}{e^{-\cos(0-0)}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
In order to do this, we can rewrite $x$ and $y$ using polar coordinates in order to show that it converges for all values of $\theta$. Doing so, we get
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\sin^4(r \cdot(\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)))}{r \cdot e^{\cos(r \cdot(\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)))}}=\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\sin^4(ar)}{r e^{\cos(br)}}$$
Now we can use l'hopitals to get
$$\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{\sin^4(ar)}{r e^{\cos(br)}}=\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{4a\sin^3(ar) \cos(ar)}{e^{\cos(br)}+br\sin(br)e^{\cos(br)}}=0$$
That last part is equal to $0$ because around $r=0$, we have $e^{\cos(cr)}=e$ and $\sin(cr) = 0$, so the top is $0$ and the bottom is $e$. Thus we have shown that the function is differentiable and that each partial derivative is $0$.